# Good practice for 2 virtual methods that delegate the work to each other

Tags: c#, oop, overriding

Following situation:
An interface declares 2 methods which do the same action with different parameters.

```
interface IX
{
  string DoTheThing(A a);
  string DoTheThing(B b);
}
```

Now objects of A can be converted to B with some cost and vice versa.
Thus we might want to use an abstract class instead of the interface that would look something like that:

```
abstract class X
{
  public virtual string DoTheThing(A a) { return DoTheThing(a.ConvertToB()); }
  public virtual string DoTheThing(B b) { return DoTheThing(b.ConvertToA()); }
}
```

This way a subclass needs to implement only 1 of the methods if wanted.
However, it also **must** implement at least one of them, otherwise we get an infinite recursion.
One question is now, whether i should make one of the methods abstract and enforce the implementation?
The problem with that is that i'd have to pick one of the methods and it might be the wrong one for
some of the subclasses and result in more conversions.

So the second question is about whether i'm missing a better solution by some language features or better
design decisions (or whether i'm overthinking this)?

P.S I'm working with C#, but the answer doesn't need to be restricted to C#.

Comment: Ca't you have an interface with only one method, and an extension method for the other?

Comment: Seems a bit Hardcoded. Why not create an interface or abstract class for your convertable entities with a method `ConvertToType(Type t)` that returns the interface or base class. Inside that method you could handle conversion according to the given type.